# uncertified servers certifivate pop-up on PyCharm,what shoul i do?

Tags: python, pycharm

There is a continuous pop-up message in PyCharm that displays `Untrusted Server's Certificate@...`. What should I do to get rid of this pop-up?

[image: Server's certificate is not trusted]

Comment: Have you asked your IT Administrator about the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to automatically accept "non-trusted" certificates but this should only be used if you are absolutely sure you are on a safe network.

If it's the certificate that is causing the popup, it's better to talk to your administrator and get it added to the trusted-certificates list.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-server-certificates.html